# How to Transfer funds to non-connected Stripe account

Tags: stripe-payments

I am charging a using through stripe.Later i want to transfer winning amount to their stripe account as i already got their stripe_user_id while creating a charge.Now i am using stripe transfer API to transfer amount to their account but i am getting error that you cannot transfer to a non-connected stripe account . Currently i am using the flow of connected account but that is long process in which user fills forms and provide their business details but they are just normal user?How to make the transfers to non-connected stripe account?

Comment: This is not possible. To transfer funds between two accounts, they must be connected.

Comment: I have made accounts connected but now its giving error that Cannot transfer to a destination that is connected with read_only scope but in actual i give read_write both

Comment: What kind of account did you create? How did you onboard it?